# ubuntu tries to force a high resolution and my screen can't handle it

Tags: display, display-resolution, xrandr

my screen just turns off when ubuntu starts. I searched everywhere over the internet for this issue and it turns out that the screen turns off because the resolution is too high.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> doesn't turn on the screen, so I restarted and entered through fail safe graphics.

I tried `xrandr` but it just keeps telling me **can't open display**. I tried to eliminate this issue too and nothing suggested on the internet works. it just kept giving me that error.

I tried editing `monitors.xml` to have a lower resolution and that doesn't work too.

I think I need to somehow enter ubuntu in normal mode, login blindly, and somehow lower the resolution without seeing what I am clicking.

Comment: Could you be more descriptive about your issue? Is this an external monitor? Your attached screen? Are you using a laptop or a desktop? Are you trying to use a graphics card or a port attached to your motherboard?

Comment: i use my normal monitor, dell u2515h. my GPU is radeon r5 230.
the problem is here: gpu is supposed to support 2560x1440 resolution with a VGI cable. the monitor though doesn't have a VGI entrance. so i am using a VGI to HDMI cable. i think the problem is here but i don't have another cable so i just need to somehow lower my resolution. right now i am using the cable in fail safe graphics mode and it works fine, but the resolution is ridiculously low.
also this is a desktop not laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I fixed it. I booted with 'Failsafe Graphics Mode', then went to 'Startup Applications', and then added a command to set to a lower resolution:

```
xrandr --output DVI-0 --mode 2048x1152
```